# Burp Suite doesn't get HTTP requests that the script make

Tags: python-requests, proxy, burp

I have a proxy named Burp Suite that is running on my local host, port 8080.

When I try to intercept HTTP request that my browser make, Burp Suite works without any issue but when it comes to intercept HTTP request my python script makes, it doesn't get any of the HTTP requests.

This is the script I run:

```py
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://example.com/?"
proxies = {
    "http" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "https" : "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
}
for num in range(10):

    newURL = url + str(num)
    r = requests.get(url=newURL, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

I tried everything I found on the internet to fix the problem, however none of them worked.

**Note:** *I changed my OS from Ubuntu to Windows 11. In Ubuntu I haven't encountered such a problem*.

**Solution:** `pip install urllib3==1.25.11` worked for me. Now everything works fine.

Comment: If you run tcpdump or wireshark, do you see the python script making direct conections, or is nothing sent at all?

Comment: Nothing is being sent. Interestingly when I remove proxy dictionary, everything works fine. @Buffoonism

Comment: Looks like it was a library bug: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6139